# can a "%H:%M:%S" datetime object be made numeric data type with same "%H:%M:%S" format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numeric

I have a column of epoch duration's.

Converted it to date-time objects in form `%H:%M:%S.`

But while plotting it, pandas demand for numeric data type.

After a search on stack-overflow I only found changing %H:%M:%S to seconds.

Is there a way to retain `"%H:%M:%S"` format and make these date-time objects to numeric ??

Comment: why not convert it to UTC or seconds and then use it to plot or are you trying to use it in the x-axis?

Comment: You can plot datetime objects in pandas no problem..What is your code?

Comment: There is no way for a number to be in a colon-delimited format, no. You can probably coerce Pandas into displaying epoch seconds in this format on the plot, though.

Comment: while plotting the datetime objects which is in `%H:%M:%S` format ...it asks for a numeric value 'TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot' @johnashu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your code is but here is an example of a standard way to plot a datetime axis in pandas using matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates

# Generate some RANDOM DATA and plot it

time = pd.date_range('07/11/2014', periods=1000, freq='5min')
ts = pd.Series(pd.np.random.randn(len(time)), index=time)
ts = pd.DataFrame(ts).reset_index()
ts.columns = ["Time", "Value"]

print(ts.head())

# START PLOT HERE!!!
xs = dates.date2num(ts['Time'])
hfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=15)
ax.plot(xs, ts['Value'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This code gives this error `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (8000,)` @johnashu

Comment: It is an example.  You need to factor it into your code.  You are using the `time` from the example  as the `x axis` and something else from your own code for the `y axis`.

Comment: I have edited it for you..  Change `ts` to whatever your `dataframe` is

Comment: I am just talking about this program you have provided ,wanted to see its execution, nothing at all related to my query. Your program is giving 'ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (8000,)'

Comment: yep, Python2.7 on spyder idle @johnashu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176402/discussion-between-surya-rahul-and-johnashu).